# How can I get grouped boxplots for each value on the x axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am using a code suggested by someone in another question about grouped boxplots, but mine looks like this

[image: single boxplots]

instead. I should have 3-4 boxplots (Week in code below) per treatment but they aren't showing up. How can I fix this?

```r
w <- Exp1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Treatment, `Vertical Travel Distance (mm)`, fill=Week)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits=unique(Exp1$Treatment)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Use `fill=factor(Week)`, remove `scale_x_discrete`, it's doing nothing. Or pipe `Exp1%>%mutate(Week=factor(Week))%>%ggplot(etc)` to make the legend title prettier.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you for the note - I will for future questions!

Comment: @RuiBarradas That worked - thank you! I include scale_x_discrete to keep the x axis in the order I want rather than alphabetical.

Comment: @MartinGal That didn't work for me but I appreciate the suggestion!